# Yellowblack stripes occuring in Flutter app

Tags: flutter

When i expand the "Tickets" option, which is in Expansion Tile, Yellow-black screen appears on my screen saying(bottom overflowed by 3 pixels). I think it is an scroll issue. How do i fix it?

```
 return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        // TRY THIS: Try changing the color here to a specific color (to
        // Colors.amber, perhaps?) and trigger a hot reload to see the AppBar
        // change color while the other colors stay the same.
        backgroundColor: Color(0xFF781B1B),
        // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
        // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
        foregroundColor: Colors.white,
        title: Text(widget.page),
      ),
      body: PageBody(widget.page),
      drawer: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
          width: 250,
          child: Drawer(
            backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onPrimary,
            child: Column(
              // Important: Remove any padding from the ListView.
              children: <Widget>[
                DrawerHeader(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                  child: UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
                    accountName: Text(
                      name,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 18.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                    accountEmail:
                        null, // If you don't want to display an email, set it to null
                    currentAccountPicture: CircleAvatar(
                      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                      child: Icon(
                        Icons.person,
                        color:
                            Color(0xFF781B1B), // Change to your desired color
                        size: 48.0, // Adjust the size as needed
                      ),
                    ),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Color(0xFF781B1B),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                ListTile(
                  leading: const Icon(Icons.account_box),
                  title: const Text('Profile'),
                  selected: _selectedIndex == 0,
                  onTap: () {
                    // Update the state of the app
                    if (_selectedIndex == 0) return;
                    GoRouter.of(context).pop();
                    GoRouter.of(context).push("/show_profile");
                    setState(() {
                      _selectedIndex = 0;
                    });

                    // Then close the drawer
                  },
                ),
                ExpansionTile(
                  leading: Icon(Icons.confirmation_num),
                  title: Text('Tickets'),
                  initiallyExpanded: _selectedIndex == 1,
                  onExpansionChanged: (bool expanded) {
                    if (expanded) {
                      // The tile is expanded, update the selected index or perform other actions.
                      setState(() {
                        _selectedIndex = 1;
                      });
                    }
                  },
                  children: <Widget>[
                    ListTile(
                      leading: Icon(Icons.confirmation_num),
                      title: Text('Choose Ticket'),
                      onTap: () {
                        GoRouter.of(context).pop();
                        GoRouter.of(context).push("/ticket_choose");
                      },
                    ),
                    ListTile(
                      leading: Icon(Icons.history),
                      title: Text('Ticket History'),
                      onTap: () {
                        GoRouter.of(context).pop();
                        GoRouter.of(context).push("/ticket_history");
                      },
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
               
               
               
                ListTile(
                  //show_requisition
                  leading: const Icon(Icons.mail),
                  title: const Text('Requisition'),
                  selected: _selectedIndex == 7,
                  onTap: () {
                    if (_selectedIndex == 7) return;
                    // Update the state of the app
                    // _onItemTapped(2);
                    GoRouter.of(context).pop();
                    GoRouter.of(context).push("/user_requisition");
                    setState(() {
                      _selectedIndex = 7;
                    });
                    // Then close the drawer
                  },
                ),
                ListTile(
                  //show_requisition
                  leading: const Icon(Icons.history),
                  title: const Text('Show Requisition'),
                  selected: _selectedIndex == 8,
                  onTap: () {
                    if (_selectedIndex == 8) return;
                    // Update the state of the app
                    // _onItemTapped(2);
                    GoRouter.of(context).pop();
                    GoRouter.of(context).push("/show_requisition");
                    // Then close the drawer
                    setState(() {
                      _selectedIndex = 8;
                    });
                  },
                ),
               
                Expanded(
                  child: Align(
                    alignment: FractionalOffset.bottomCenter,
                    child: ListTile(
                      visualDensity: const VisualDensity(vertical: 4),
                      leading: const Icon(Icons.logout),
                      title: const Text('Log out'),
                      selected: false,
                      onTap: () async {
                        var r1 = await Requests.post(
                            'http://18.117.93.134:6969/api/logout');
                        r1.raiseForStatus();
                        dynamic json1 = r1.json();
                        if (json1['success']) {
                          await Requests.clearStoredCookies(
                              "18.117.93.134:6969");
                          Fluttertoast.showToast(
                              msg: 'Logged out.',
                              toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
                              gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM,
                              timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
                              backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(73, 77, 65, 64),
                              textColor: Colors.white,
                              fontSize: 16.0);
                          GoRouter.of(context).go("/login");
                        }
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

If I reduce no of List tiles, the problem goes away. But I don't want to reduce no of tiles. SO what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

When the content within a widget exceeds the allowed space, causing the layout to overflow, the "bottom overflowed by x.xx pixels" error happens. In your example, the overflow is brought on by the fact that there are too many ListTile widgets in your ExpansionTile widget.

You can wrap your ExpansionTile in a SingleChildScrollView to enable scrolling inside the expansion region in order to resolve this problem without reducing the number of tiles. The following is how to change your code:

```
ExpansionTile(
  leading: Icon(Icons.confirmation_num),
  title: Text('Tickets'),
  initiallyExpanded: _selectedIndex == 1,
  onExpansionChanged: (bool expanded) {
    if (expanded) {
      // The tile is expanded, update the selected index or perform other actions.
      setState(() {
        _selectedIndex = 1;
      });
    }
  },
  children: <Widget>[
    SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.confirmation_num),
            title: Text('Choose Ticket'),
            onTap: () {
              // push/pop navigation logic will be here as per req.
            },
          ),
          ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.history),
            title: Text('Ticket History'),
            onTap: () {
              // push/pop navigation logic will be here as per req.
            },
          ),
          // Add more ListTiles here if needed
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```

You can avoid the overflow problem and maintain all of your tiles by enclosing the Column of ListTile widgets inside a SingleChildScrollView. This allows the content to scroll within the expansion region.

By using this strategy, you ought to be able to keep the desired amount of tiles while avoiding the overflow error.